# OleDbException: Function is not implemented

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb, foxpro, oledbconnection

Does anyone knows what happened? it it does delete all records, but still return an exception

```
    OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=C:\foxpro");

    try
    {
        dbConn.Open();
        using (OleDbCommand command = dbConn.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "execscript[('USE table in 0' + chr(13) + chr(10) + 'DELETE ALL')]";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();       
        }            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        dbConn.Close();
    }
```

The exception is:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Function is not implemented. at
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr) at
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult) at 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult) at
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult) at 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) at
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at backbuttonclicked.Page_Load(Object sender,
EventArgs e) in e:\MyProjects\programs\FujiDocumentsPrinting\backbuttonclicked.aspx.cs:line 31
```

Comment: Is it possible that the Foxpro tables belong to a database container (.DBC)? If so, perhaps there is logic in the DBC that is cauing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tablename1";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This will delete all records from the file also. File 'tablename1.dbf' should be placed at 'C:\foxpro\' folder. Otherwise, use full file name in the SQL command text.

Comment: by using OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0, error disappear

Answer (score 0):

I have had success doing this kind of thing with the following code:

```
 string connectionString = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=c:\foxpro"; 

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) 
    { 
        using (OleDbCommand scriptCommand = connection.CreateCommand()) 
        { 
            connection.Open();

            string vfpScript = @"SET EXCLUSIVE ON
                                USE table
                                DELETE ALL
                                PACK"; 

            scriptCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
            scriptCommand.CommandText = "ExecScript"; 
            scriptCommand.Parameters.Add("myScript", OleDbType.Char).Value = vfpScript; 
            scriptCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        } 
    }
```

`DELETE ALL` will mark the records as deleted but not remove them from the table. If this is what you want then remove the `PACK` command which removes all records marked as deleted from the dbf.

Comment: i copied your code and change the table name, it does pack all deleted record but still return an exception Function is not implemented.

Comment: What is the code on `programs\FujiDocumentsPrinting\backbuttonclicked.aspx.cs:line 31` ?

Comment: ZAP could replace the 2 lines: "DELETE ALL" and "PACK"

Answer (score 0):

You have a try catch in one of your triggers, that's the feature that is not implemented. Ran into the same issue today.